# How to Access database via WampServer 1.7.3 from another Computer in A LAN?

Tags: php, networking, wampserver, lan, wamp-protocol

A web application is hosted in a local computer  on WampServer 1.7.3.
How can access the database from another computer via LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Step   1

First you need to set up the WAMP service on your server and on the required services. And make sure that your WAMP server is online and it’s running on your browser using http://localhot:8081/ (I have given a fixed port number 8081 to my WAMP server). For more information please refer to the WAMP setup instruction at this URL:http://www.bulletprooftemplates.com/how-to-install-wamp-20.

To run the WAMP Apache server on your specified port, do the following. Go in the\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\httpd.conf file and search for “#Listen” and then change the port from 80 to 8081 and in that case, your URL will behttp://localhost:8081/. Like below:

Hide   Copy Code

## Listen 12.34.56.78:80 Listen 192.168.1.154:8081

Step 2

Now make the WMAP Server accessible in the LAN or WAN, you have to get\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\conf\httpd.conf and open it and find the following code:

Hide   Copy Code

AllowOverride None Options None Order allow,deny Deny from all

And change the above code to:

Hide   Copy Code

AllowOverride None Options None Order allow,deny Allow from all

Step 3

Now you have to bind the server static IP to the port number (remember we gave done this in the start) so for this you have be on the same file and change “Listen 8081”  to “Listen [IP Address  of Server]:8081”. It will look  like “Listen 192.168.1.154:8081”.

Hide   Copy Code

Listen 192.168.1.154:8081

Step 4

Great! The next step is to open port (8081) of the server such that everyone can access your server. This depends on which OS you are using. Like if you are using Windows Vista, then follow the below steps.

Open Control Panel  >> System and Security >> Windows Firewall then click on “Advance Setting” and then select“Inbound Rules” from the left panel and then click on “Add Rule…”. Select “PORT” as an option from the list and then in the next screen select “TCP” protocol and enter port number “8081” under “Specific local port” then click on the”Next” button and select “Allow the Connection” and then give the general name and description to this port and click Done.

Now you are done with PORT opening as well.

Next is “Restart All Services” of WAMP and access your machine in LAN or WAN.